# Merged collection with multiple models, how to loop through them in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I was wondering what the best way is to loop through a Laravel collection in blade that contains multiple model types. In my case for example I have a collection containing comments and proposals.

`ConversationsController`:

```
$conversation->comments = $conversation->comments->merge($conversation->proposals)->sortBy('created_at');
```

`show.blade.php`:

```
@foreach($conversation->comments as $collection)
     @if(get_class($collection) === 'App\Models\ConversationComment')
         @include('partials/comment', ['comment' => $collection])
     @else
         @include('partials/proposal', ['proposal' => $collection])
     @endif
@endforeach
```

This implementation I came up with works. But feels a bit weird.

So, what would be the Laravel way to do this?

Comment: why do you need to merge them on your contoller only to "split" them again in your view?

Comment: Because I want them to be shown in one listing. Ordered by the create_at prop.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want them to be merged because you want to sort them by `created_at` and then have them be displayed mixed together in the list.

Even though this looks dirty - this is the only way to do it if you want to keep them merged together.

There are some code golf options that are available for this, but it all boils down to same thing.

You could use just one partial called

```php
@foreach($conversation->comments as $item)
     @include('partials/commentItem', ['item' => $item])
@endforeach
```

And then have that partial have something like this inside:

```php
@if(get_class($item) === 'App\Models\ConversationComment')
  @include('partials/comment', ['comment' => $item])
@else
  @include('partials/proposal', ['proposal' => $item])
@endif
```

But what I would suggest to you is to try to make Data Transfer Object that will encapsulate all the things that should be displayed for both of them and then just use one single partial that will display it, as I believe both of those share same properties.

For example, if you want to display only comment/proposal text + date it was added + who left that comment/proposal, then you could merge your comments and proposals together and map them in a way that they are displayable in uniform form, for example:

```php
$conversation->comments = $conversation->comments->merge($conversation->proposals)->sortBy('created_at');

$conversation->comments = $conversation->comments->map(function ($value) {
  return [
    'text' => $value->text, 
    'created_at' => $value->created_at, 
    'added_by' => $value->added_by
  ];
});
```

And then in your blade, you don't have to do check on their class type, but just go through all items and call `text`, `created_at` and `added_by` as needed.

For some more details on DTOs you can check this: [https://medium.com/@eloufirhatim/what-is-dto-and-how-to-use-it-in-a-laravel-application-7ca1e9045985#:~:text=DTO%20stands%20for%20Data%20Transfer,different%20parts%20of%20the%20application](https://medium.com/@eloufirhatim/what-is-dto-and-how-to-use-it-in-a-laravel-application-7ca1e9045985#:%7E:text=DTO%20stands%20for%20Data%20Transfer,different%20parts%20of%20the%20application).

Or you can check this library: https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-data/v3/introduction

Comment: Just wanted to point out that a proposal contains quite diffirent fields then a comment does. So the last example isn't an option for me. I can't treat the models like they have the same fields.

Comment: Then unfortunately your option is the only way to go if that's the case.